# Do not select if the parent class is hidden

Tags: jquery

With the code below I am selecting all checkboxes and all radio buttons to send them to an array.

```
var options = [];
$('.option input[type="checkbox"]:checked, .option input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {
    options.push($(this).val());
});
var options_checked = options.join(',');
```

There are some single radio buttons which have the parent class `sass_syntax` and of course they also get selected. I don't want to select them if the class `sass_syntax` is hidden (`display: none`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude them using a [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter

```
var options = $('.option input[type="checkbox"]:checked, .option input[type=radio]:checked').not('.sass_syntax:hidden input').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
var options_checked = options.join(',');
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check it with `:not()`

```
var options = [];
$('.option input[type="checkbox"]:checked, .option input[type=radio]:checked:not(.sass_syntax:hidden)').each(function() {
    options.push($(this).val());
});
var options_checked = options.join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery 'hasClass' to find the class in input checkbox/radiobutton's parent element

```
var options = [];
$('.option input[type="checkbox"]:checked, .option input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('sass')){
       $(this).parent().hide();
       return;
    }
    options.push($(this).val());

});
var options_checked = options.join(',');
```